# flutter storage permission problem on android

Tags: android, flutter

I have storage permission problem on android. storage didn't granted permission. sdkversion is 33 and used `permission_handler: ^10.2.0`. i make a permission request and check isGranted, i got false.

i've also put all the user-permission related to storage in AndroidManifext.xml.

```dart
Permission.storage.request();
Permission.storage.status.isGranted; # false
```

Purpose requiring storage permission is to create a directory and read & write a file. And one weird thing is that when you go into app info, there's no permission for storage, there's music and audio, photos and videos. (reference attached image) so, i touched audio, photos permission but if i create a directory, `(OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)` apears. oh! i also touched manage storage permission but it's not.

- i tried `flutter clean`

help me....

[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKaf4.png)

---

currently my code is...

```dart
    bool permissionGranted = false;

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final androidInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
      if (androidInfo.version.sdkInt <= 32) {
        Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> permissions = await [
          Permission.storage,
          Permission.microphone,
        ].request();
        permissionGranted = permissions[Permission.storage]!.isGranted &&
            permissions[Permission.microphone]!.isGranted;
      } else {
        Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> permissions = await [
          Permission.photos,
          Permission.microphone,
        ].request();
        permissionGranted = permissions[Permission.photos]!.isGranted &&
            permissions[Permission.microphone]!.isGranted;
      }
    }
    
    Directory directory = Directory('/storage/recordings');
    await directory.create(recursive: true); // this error
```

---

### AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.keyword_speech">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />

...

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

...
```

Comment: The permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is no longer working on Android: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#permissions-target-any

Comment: If your app has a rightful purpose to manage the storage, you can go on with that page: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files (If you need to upload to Playstore read the policies on this page). Alternatively think about using e.g. Storage Access Framework (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) depending on your use cases.

Comment: @Christopher thanks for your answer. and i tried manage the storage but it's not solved it.(directory create error) i need a solution or reference for dart & flutter user. .

Comment: `Directory('/storage/recordings')` That is an impossible path. Please choose a possible path.

Comment: @blackapps right... As you said, the path is wrong. so, I solved it using **path_provider**. `await getExternalStorageDirectory()` Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ridiculously, path is wrong.... I solved it using **path_provider**.

```dart
await getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to write permissions in AndroidManifest like this -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
```

Don't know your exact problem but this can a solution.